# How to construct generic without protocol in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics

I'm getting the following error...

`'T' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers`

When compiling...

```
class Sub<T : Equitable> {
    func def(v : T) -> Bool{
        var d = T()          // <- Error
        return d == v
    }
}
var s = Sub<Int>()
println(s.def(0), s.def(1))  // I'm expecting "true, false"
```

I understand that in order for a generic type to be initialized, it needs to conform to a protocol that contains an `init()` constructor. Such as...

```
protocol A : Equitable {
    init()
}

class Sub<T : A> {
```

But then I would get get the error

`Type 'Int' does not conform to protocol 'A'`

at the line

`var s = Sub<Int>()`

So how would I go about making a value type such as Int or Bool conform to a protocol that can be initialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extend Int like so for it to adopt protocol A:

```
class Sub<T : A> {
    func def(v : T) -> Bool{
        var d = T()  
        return d == v
    }
}

protocol A : Equatable {
    init()
}

extension Int: A {

}

var s = Sub<Int>()
s.def(0) // true
s.def(1))  // false
```

Comment: So if I wanted to use this class for Int, UInt, Bool, etc. I would have to add an extension for each type?

Comment: Yes that's correct, adopting a new protocol is an extension